# Closing/Removing a tab item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs

I have a tab control in a window. The tabs all have simple context menus which (are supposed to) allow the user to close them. However, when I click close, nothing happens.

Here is the event handler

```
void closeTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tabs.Items.Remove((MenuItem)sender);
}
```

I've looked around about closing tabs, but none of the articles I found went into much detail about how to actually close the tab.

New problem:

```
void closeTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MenuItem close = (MenuItem)sender; 
    Tabs.Items.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(close.Name.Remove(0,3))); 
}
```

The context menu item is named thusly:

```
Name = "Tab" + Tabs.Items.Count.ToString(),
```

It still does nothing

Comment: What is "Tabs"? Cant find the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu item is not the tab. You cannot remove it from the `TabControl`. You need a reference to the tab to which the `MenuItem` belongs. This can be done in various ways.

---

I see you tried some rather hacky things there with names and string manipulation, here would be a more clean approach which does not require any of that:

```
var target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
while (target is ContextMenu == false)
    target = (FrameworkElement)target.Parent;
var tabItem = (target as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget;
Tabs.Items.Remove(tabItem);
```

This gets the parent until it finds the `ContextMenu` and gets the `TabItem` from the `PlacementTarget`.

Comment: What was I thinking!?!? How did I miss that. I thought it said TabItem. DUURRR

Comment: @Luke: If you need help obtaining the tab, let me know.

Comment: Okay... Now I have a genuine issue.

Comment: I really need to think about these things more. I think I know the problem.

Comment: I have fixed it. You can't remove from the items collection using just an index... oh, yes I can. RemoveAt() is what I wanted.

Comment: @Luke: I added a suggestion of how to get the tab to my answer.

Comment: That's a lot better, thanks. I am still relatively new to WPF, so I don't yet know about everything that can be used.

Comment: @Luke: Actually even better might be using [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) and passing the `TabItem` as `CommandParameter` in XAML. As you are new to WPF you might find [all the articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) to be useful.