# How to delete a Tab Item based off of it's name or header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275145/search-through-tab-control-for-specific-tab-item-based-on-a-string-value/18275728?noredirect=1#18275728) I asked earlier today. The difference is, now I would like to delete a Tab Item referenced by it's `name` or `header`. Can I call `Remove` in a fashion similar to the answer I got on this question?

This is what I've tried:

```
tabControl.Items.Remove = tabControl.Items //Changes tab according to TreeView
                        .OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == stringValue);
```

Can I use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272084/closing-removing-a-tab-item-wpf)? If so, how?

Comment: I strongly suggest MVVM as the default way of thinking for WPF. winforms-like code-behind type of hacks and manipulating UI elements in procedural code will only bring you pain and suffering and torture and miserable failure. Much more so when you're dealing with `ItemsControl`-derived elements (such as TabControl or Menu or ListBox or ComboBox).

Comment: It doesn't exactly work because `Remove` is a method group. I'll post what I tried.

Comment: Remove is not a property, you cannot assign a value to it

Comment: Really, with the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about removing from wpf, however this code is way more likely to work than what you have posted.  Remove is a method, you can't assign it a value, so you have to isolate the item you want to remove, check to make sure it isn't null, then pass the object into the `Remove` method.

```
var tabToDelete = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == stringValue);
if (tabToDelete != null) // Since you chose to use SingleOrDefault, we have to check to make sure it isn't null before we try to remove it.
tabControl.Items.Remove(tabToDelete);
```

However, I strongly suggest you take a look at [WPF - Best way to remove an item from the ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271576/wpf-best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-the-itemssource) since it goes into details about checking IF the item CAN be removed, and even if the Remove method is available to that control.

Comment: Can I change `Name` to `Header` and use this code to reference the `tabItem` by `Header`?