# Delete a Tab Item based off of its header

Tags: c#, wpf, header, tabitem

First of all, this question is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278781/how-to-delete-a-tab-item-based-off-of-its-name-or-header). I feel like I only got half of my question answered.

As well as deleting `tabItems` referenced by `Name`, I also need to be able to delete `tabItems` by referencing their `Headers`.

When implementing my answer and changing `n.Name` to `n.Header`, like so:

```
var tabToDelete = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Header == stringValue);
if (tabToDelete != null) 
tabControl.Items.Remove(tabToDelete);
```

I find that it does not work the same. Should this work, or do I need to edit this whole structure? If so how would I do that to make sure the `tabItem` I need is referenced by `Header`?

**Addition**: When the tabs referenced by `Name` are deleted, they are taken off of the screen, whereas the tabs reference by `Header` are not (until you manually switch tabs). This leads me to think that they are still existing in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Header` is an object and not a string. You're comparing the two values as if they are, but because Header is an object you're actually doing a reference comparison, not a value comparison. You need to cast `Header` to a string by simply calling `.ToString()` on `Header`.

```
var tabToDelete = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(n => (n.Header as string) == stringValue);
if (tabToDelete != null)
    tabControl.Items.Remove(tabToDelete);
```

If this doesn't solve the problem you can force the control to redraw by calling

```
tabControl.Refresh();
```

### Update

Credit to Daniel Gimenez for spotting the possible null reference exception. The issue of the `Header` being set to a control is not a problem however, as all objects can call `ToString()`, the real problem is if the `Header` is not set at all, resulting in a `null` object.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ryan said, the problem is that `Header` can be a control instead of just text.  If `Header` can be `null`, `as String` or `Convert.ToString()` will be better than `toString()` because they can both handle converting from null values whereas `ToString()` produces an exception.

Using `Convert.ToString()` might be overkill, but if your Headers are bound to values that can't implicitly convert to strings, such as integers, then using `Convert.ToString()` will be able to handle them.  Also this solution will handle the case if multiple items with the same header value exist.

```
private void RemoveTabByHeader(string str) 
{
    TabsMain.Items.OfType<TabItem>().Where(t => Convert.ToString(t.Header) == str)
       .ToList().ForEach(t => TabsMain.Items.Remove(t));
}
```

This is tested.  The `TabControl` correctly updates.